# Why has my Photoshop CS6 Liquify preview function stopped working?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In the liquify window, I can't see changes made realtime, I only see the changes once I click 'ok', leave the liquify window and go back to my image where I can then see that the changes have been made.

Using any of the tools won't show as I use them.

I updated my Macbook Pro which is a 2.53Ghz 8gig 17 inch

It was working originally, but at some point stopped. I've reinstalled and deleted preferences. I've zoomed in and out and tried with large and small file image sizes. I've closed out all other programs as well.

Comment: No third part plugins and it is the latest version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is broad, we need to rule out what it could be. Some of these suggestions may seem obvious but please do try them all.

> Set "Show backdrop" mode to "behind" in the Liquify screen.

1. Update your video drivers
2. Ensure you're using the latest version (with the latest patches etc)
3. Remove all plug ins and try again to see if it's a conflict.
4. Ensure it's not an issue with what you're trying by doing something simple.
5. Create a new canvas, with 1 white background, and on a new layer, add a  green line down the middle. With the new layer selected, try and manipulate it in the liquify screen.
6. Uncheck the 'backgroup' settings in the Liquify screen
7. Make sure you're actually working on the correct layer

[Source](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/846326?start=0&tstart=0)